# Cat has watery eye

Tags: cats, health, medicines, diseases

My cat has been sneezing for the last week at least once a day, but I have thought nothing of it. Today I can home and one of his eyes looks more watery than usual and the corner of his eye looks a little irritated and red. Should I wait and see if the symptoms clear or worsen or immediately take him to the vet?

Comment: My cat ended up having an upper respiratory infection, pink eye, and a fever

Answer (score 4):

I think going to the vet is the right thing to do now.

The cat has been sneezing for a week, so this is more than cats normally sneeze.

Your cat's eyes look irritated, and while this might be normal, it has lasted for some time, so you need to get it looked at by the vet.

The combination of sneezing and irritated eyes makes me think there might be an allergy or an infection going on.

So get on the phone and get an appointment with your vet and get this looked at.

Comment: It sounds exactly like an upper respiratory infection with conjunctivitis; going to the vet is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the vet before the condition gets worse.
It's looking like an indication of some allergic type of reaction. And the redness and irritation are because of the allergens.
But in case of problems with vets: without observing the patient, no one can say one hundred percent it's an allergic condition.
So it's better to visit a doctor.